# Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Tags: ios, crash-reports

I have uploaded my app in appstore and my app got rejected due to some crash.So I though the crash would be with my app and I have tested in all iphone with simulators  IOS 9.2,8.2,8.1,8.4 but I didnt get any crash in my app but I got a crash log from Apple store ...help me on this Thanks you in advance

```html
Incident Identifier: E84A5BEF-5EA5-4957-8DFA-3A17BECE6A4D
CrashReporter Key:   c614652a8cbcbf1b4c6bb92123ad0cf98e765ffc
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Stampivity [1021]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CAD27DB1-2EF6-4396-8951-107804E17F17/Stampivity.app/Stampivity
Identifier:          com.stampivity
Version:             1.9 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-01-05 09:39:08.08 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-01-05 09:35:51.51 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2 (13C75)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18382d900 0x182e9bf80 0x183713828 0x1000ba98c 0x1841e244c 0x1837e55f4 0x1837e5298 0x1837e29ac 0x183711680 0x184c20088 0x188588d90 0x1000c6048 0x1832b28b8)

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
1.403781     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183e0584c TCP Conn 0x12550e6e0 SSL Handshake DONE
1.593277     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183e0575c TCP Conn 0x12550e6e0 starting SSL negotiation
1.594258     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea7104 TCP Conn 0x12550e6e0 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
1.595202     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea8630 TCP Conn 0x12550e6e0 event 1. err: 0
1.696725     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea8708 TCP Conn 0x12550e6e0 started
65.520503    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184e92b54 [0x126275600] Releasing session
65.522272    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184e94ff4 [0x1262bf600] Decoding completed without errors
65.527160    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184e9318c [0x1262bf600] Options: 200x200 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
65.527160    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184e93044 [0x1262bf600] Decoding: C2 0x00C800C8 0x00003842 0x22111100 0x00000000 9596
65.535398    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000184e92338 [0x1262bf600] Created session
65.591056    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183e0584c TCP Conn 0x127303250 SSL Handshake DONE
65.711415    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183e0575c TCP Conn 0x127303250 starting SSL negotiation
65.712156    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea7104 TCP Conn 0x127303250 complete. fd: 27, err: 0
65.713383    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea8630 TCP Conn 0x127303250 event 1. err: 0
65.771353    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea8708 TCP Conn 0x127303250 started
65.869010    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183e0584c TCP Conn 0x127044850 SSL Handshake DONE
65.987083    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183e0575c TCP Conn 0x127044850 starting SSL negotiation
65.987490    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea7104 TCP Conn 0x127044850 complete. fd: 21, err: 0
65.988423    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea8630 TCP Conn 0x127044850 event 1. err: 0
66.045470    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ea8708 TCP Conn 0x127044850 started
67.937362    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183e0584c TCP Conn 0x1271dddc0 SSL Handshake DONE
68.122177    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183e0575c TCP Conn 0x1271dddc0 starting SSL negotiation




Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833d0140 0x1833b4000 + 115008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183498ef8 0x183494000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000183341e4c 0x1832e0000 + 400972
3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x0000000183341db8 0x1832e0000 + 400824
4   libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000182e753f4 0x182e74000 + 5108
5   libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000182e91e98 0x182e74000 + 122520
6   libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000182e9c248 0x182e94000 + 33352
7   Stampivity                     0x00000001002e7b70 0x1000a8000 + 2358128
8   libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000182e8ef44 0x182e74000 + 110404
9   libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000182e8eb10 0x182e74000 + 109328
10  libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000000182e9c120 0x182e94000 + 33056
11  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183711728 0x183708000 + 38696
12  GraphicsServices               0x0000000184c20088 0x184c14000 + 49288
13  UIKit                          0x0000000188588d90 0x18850c000 + 511376
14  Stampivity                     0x00000001000c6048 0x1000a8000 + 122952
15  libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001832b28b8 0x1832b0000 + 10424

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833d14fc 0x1833b4000 + 120060
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018329494c 0x183280000 + 84300
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001832837bc 0x183280000 + 14268

Thread 2 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833b54bc 0x1833b4000 + 5308
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833b5338 0x1833b4000 + 4920
2   Stampivity                     0x00000001002d641c 0x1000a8000 + 2286620
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183497b28 0x183494000 + 15144
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183497a8c 0x183494000 + 14988
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495028 0x183494000 + 4136

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833b54bc 0x1833b4000 + 5308
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833b5338 0x1833b4000 + 4920
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001837e4ac0 0x183708000 + 903872
3   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001837e27c4 0x183708000 + 894916
4   CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183711680 0x183708000 + 38528
5   CFNetwork                      0x0000000183e81434 0x183dd4000 + 709684
6   Foundation                     0x00000001841efc40 0x1840fc000 + 998464
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183497b28 0x183494000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183497a8c 0x183494000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495028 0x183494000 + 4136

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833d0368 0x1833b4000 + 115560
1   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001837eb028 0x183708000 + 929832
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183497b28 0x183494000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183497a8c 0x183494000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495028 0x183494000 + 4136

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833d0b6c 0x1833b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495530 0x183494000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495020 0x183494000 + 4128

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833d0b6c 0x1833b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495530 0x183494000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495020 0x183494000 + 4128

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833d0b6c 0x1833b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495530 0x183494000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495020 0x183494000 + 4128

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x00000001833d0b6c 0x1833b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495530 0x183494000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000183495020 0x183494000 + 4128

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000030000000300
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001a111f000  x21: 0x000000016fd57490  x22: 0x0000000000000006  x23: 0x00000001003681ef
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x39008f10a244e6f1  x26: 0x0000000125618fd0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fd573b0   lr: 0x0000000183498ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fd57390   pc: 0x00000001833d0140 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: Search for how to symbolicate a crash.  You need to turn "7   Stampivity                     0x00000001002e7b70 0x1000a8000 + 2358128" from the crashed thread into something readable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I did that even and I went through with the report but in the crash login I didnt found any of my view controller name neither method name all the crash report is regarding frame works.I didnt understood exactly where the crash is?

Comment: After a long research found how to check it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

Comment: Hi I have same issue and now I am checking according to you. Apple is telling me about and error in my code. (Last Exception Backtrace (0))

Comment: I am facing the same query but not able to find where is the crash where should i found that crash my app is not even live on AppStore.  @uttamraj

Comment: @uttamraj I am facing the same query did you got any response . I am getting this from Apple but runs perfectly fine at my end